# jquery add data to form header inside the form

Tags: jquery

So lets say once i open a page a form is created.

```
<form class='checkout_forms' action='http://www.localhost.com/' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Down below on the page inside the form i`m loading a js file and i want to add something to the  element.

```
data-stuff-encrypt-key="mykey"
```

how can i add that to the  so it would be:

```
<form data-stuff-encrypt-key="mykey" ..... >
```

Thanks

edit:
something like this inside the form:

```js
<script src='Crypt.js'> $(document).ready(function(){   
$('form.checkout_forms').attr('data-stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey'); }); </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data` method:

```
$('form.checkout_forms').data('stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey');
```

Note though that this will put the value in to jQuery's internal data cache - it will not appear as an attribute on the element in the DOM. If you want that behaviour, you would need to use `attr()`:

```
$('form.checkout_forms').attr('data-stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey');
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds

Comment: i`m jquery new but something like this ?
` <script src='Crypt.js'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('form.checkout_forms').attr('data-stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey');
 });
 </script>`

Comment: `data` is better than `attr` for this task.

Comment: You don't need `src` , just `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('form.checkout_forms').attr('data-stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey'); }); </script>`, but if you are inserting this piece of code after page load, it's not going to work.

Comment: Yes, just put this script before body tag, do not load it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('form').attr('data-stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey');
```

Or if you just want to store data and not add an actual attribute, use

```
$('form').data('stuff-encrypt-key', 'mykey');
```